# Get words and values Between Parentheses in Scala-Spark

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark

here is my data :

```
doc1: (Does,1) (just,-1) (what,0) (was,1) (needed,1) (to,0) (charge,1) (the,0) (Macbook,1)
doc2: (Pro,1) (G4,-1) (13inch,0) (laptop,1)
doc3: (Only,1) (beef,0) (was,1) (it,0) (no,-1) (longer,0) (lights,-1) (up,0) (the,-1)
etc...
```

and i want to extract words and values and then store them in two separated matrices , matrix_1 is (docID words) and matrix_2 is (docID values)  ;

Comment: whats your approach/program you worked till now??

Comment: Is all this data in 1 file? or each line in a separate file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input.txt
=========
doc1: (Does,1) (just,-1) (what,0) (was,1) (needed,1) (to,0) (charge,1) (the,0) (Macbook,1)
doc2: (Pro,1) (G4,-1) (13inch,0) (laptop,1)
doc3: (Only,1) (beef,0) (was,1) (it,0) (no,-1) (longer,0) (lights,-1) (up,0) (the,-1)
```

```
val inputText = sc.textFile("input.txt")
var digested = input.map(line => line.split(":"))
        .map(row => row(0) -> row(1).trim.split(" "))
        .map(row => row._1 -> row._2.map(_.stripPrefix("(").stripSuffix(")").trim.split(",")))

var matrix_1 = digested.map(row => row._1 -> row._2.map( a => a(0)))
var matrix_2 = digested.map(row => row._1 -> row._2.map( a => a(1)))
```

gives:

```
List(
  (doc1 -> Does,just,what,was,needed,to,charge,the,Macbook),
  (doc2 -> Pro,G4,13inch,laptop),
  (doc3 -> Only,beef,was,it,no,longer,lights,up,the)
)

List(
  (doc1 -> 1,-1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1), 
  (doc2 -> 1,-1,0,1), 
  (doc3 -> 1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1)
)
```

Comment: hi , I run it on ItelliJ IDEA but it has some errors, i also imported ( import breeze.linalg.Axis._ ) but it couldn't work

Comment: Looks like your compiler doesn't like the _ shorthand. Updated.